# how to get data from multiple custom table with ajax in wordperss

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

how to get data from multiple custom table in wordpress with ajax. I have four table in wordpress database state, city, town, pincode, i want to search result by name or pincode from database.

i have a custom search box named advanced-searchform.php in my theme

```
<form method="get" id="advanced-searchform" role="search" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

<h3><?php _e( 'Advanced Search', 'textdomain' ); ?></h3>

 <!--PASSING THIS TO TRIGGER THE ADVANCED SEARCH RESULT PAGE FROM functions.php--> 
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">

<label for="name" class=""><?php _e( 'Search By Name: ', 'textdomain' ); ?></label><br>
<input type="text" id="cityname" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Name', 'textdomain' ); ?>" name="name" />

<label for="name" class=""><?php _e( 'Search By Code: ', 'textdomain' ); ?></label><br>
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Pin Code', 'textdomain' ); ?>" name="pincode" />

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
```

Register Hook in functions.php

```
enter function wpse_load_custom_search_template(){
if( isset($_REQUEST['search']) == 'advanced' ) {
    require('advanced-search-result.php');
    die();
}}add_action('init','wpse_load_custom_search_template');
```

and for show result advanced-search-result.php

```
$keyword = $_GET['name'];
$query = "(SELECT state_name as type FROM state WHERE state_name LIKE '%" .$keyword . "%') 
       UNION
(SELECT district_name as type FROM district WHERE district_name LIKE '%" .$keyword . "%') 
       UNION
   (SELECT city_name as type FROM city WHERE city_name LIKE '%" .$keyword. "%')";

$result = $wpdb->get_results($query);var_dump($result);
```

please tell me how can get data with ajax on autocomplete, when i enter 3-4 word of data form show hint of match data from database.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you have use wrong hook for call your function to get search result.

To call a function for AJAX response you have to use following hooks:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_[actionname]', '[functionname]' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_[actionname]', '[functionname]' );

function [functionname]() {
}
```

In your jQuery code (from where you call ajax), you need to pass "action" variable along with data. Following is one example of jQuery and function.php code

jQuery Code:

```
data = {
        action : 'test',
        [other parametervalues]
};
jQuery.post('<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>', data, function(response) {           
    // code based on your response from AJAX
});
```

Code in Function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'callbackFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', 'callbackFunction' );

function callbackFunction() {
     // your code
    echo ""; // whatever you want to send in AJAX response
    die();
}
```

Please let me know if you need any further help.